# Simple Random Walk: Use Martingale to Find $E[\tau S_{\tau}]$

Tags: martingales, random-walk

Consider a simple random walk; that is, a sequence $S_n=\sum _1 ^n X_i$ where $X_i=1$ wp $\frac{1}{2}$ and $X_i=-1$ wp $\frac{1}{2}$. Let $\tau$ be the stopping time of the walk; that is, for $a,b>0$, we let $\tau = \{\min n | S_{n}=a \text{ or } S_{n}=-b\}$.

I want to calculate $E[\tau S_\tau]$. Now, it can be shown that $Z_n = S_n^3-3nS_n$ is a martingale without too much work. Thus, if we verify the conditions of the Optional Stopping Theorem, we would have $E[\tau S_\tau] = E[S_\tau ^3]$. Then, it is easy to calculate $E[S_\tau ^3]$, since it is easy to show $P(S_\tau =a)=1-P(S_\tau=-b)=\frac{b}{a+b}$.

But I cannot show that the [conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optional_stopping_theorem#Statement_of_theorem) of the optional stopping theorem hold! From that link, it seems that conditions (a) and (c) do not hold, but I cannot show that (b) holds-I know that $E[\tau]=ab<\infty$ but cannot show that $E[|Z_n-Z_{n-1}|]$ is bounded!

Comment: Use the optional stopping theorem to show that $M_n := S_{n \wedge \tau}^3 - 3 (n \wedge \tau) S_{n \wedge \tau}$ is a martingale, and then use the dominated convergence theorem to let $n \to \infty$ (using the fact that $|S_{n \wedge \tau}| \leq \max\{a,b\}$ for all $n$).

Comment: Ah, I think I see...my problem was that as $n\to \infty$ the value of $|Z_n|$ can get arbitraily large and so therefore so can $|Z_n-Z_{n-1}|$...but in fact we can never have $n>\tau$ (or we could just consider the MG indexed by $n \wedge \tau$) and so $n$ is in fact upper bounded by $\tau$ whose expectation is finite, and so the bounds are easier to work with. Do you think that sounds correct?

Comment: You really have to work with the martingal indexed by $n \wedge \tau$. (It simply doesn't make sense ot say that $n$ is upper beounded by $\tau$....) But, yes, $\tau$ has finite expectation and combining this with the fact that $|S_{n \wedge T}| \leq a \vee b$, this gives a nice integrable dominating function for $Z_{n \wedge \tau}$.